# Jinja saying `comment` undefined, when it's inside a for loop, where comment is defined

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I get this error while running a python web app using Flask:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'comment' is undefined
```

Here's the code to generate the HTML:

```
@app.route("/item")
def item():
    id = request.args.get("id", "").strip()
    return render_template("item.html", content=post.get_post_content(id))
```

The relevant code for the get_post_content function:

```
for comment in parsed_html.select(".comtr"):
    user = comment.select(".comhead .hnuser")[0].get_text()
    user_href = f"/user?id={user}"
    date = comment.select(".age a")[0].get_text()[3:]
    comment_text = comment.select(".commtext")[0].prettify().replace(" c00", "")

    comments.append({
        "user": user,
        "user_href": user_href,
        "date": date,
        "text": comment_text,
    })


return {
    "title": title,
    "site_from": site_from,
    "site": site,
    "comments": comments,
}
```

And here's the template HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title> {{ content["title"] }} </title>
    <link href={{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }} rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="comments">
    { % for comment in content["comments"] % }
      <div class="comment">
        <div class="comhead">
          <a class="user" href="{{ comment['user_href'] }}">
            {{ comment['user'] }}
          </a>
          <span class="date">
            {{ comment['date'] }}
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    { % endfor % }
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

The bit where it's saying that `comment` is undefined is `<a class="user" href="{{ comment['user_href'] }}">`, which is strange, since it's clearly in a for loop, where the var is `comment`. So I can't see any reason why `comment` is undefined.

Comment: I have very little experience with Jinja, but doesn't `{ %` need to be `{%`? And then the same for the closing tags?

Comment: What the above comment says is the issue. Because you incorrectly formatted the for loop, it doesn't get detected at all. It just skips over that line and renders what's inside as normal.

Answer (score 0):

> In Jinja loops and conditionals come under name of control structures, since they affect flow of a program. Control structures use blocks enclosed by `{%` and `%}` characters.

In your code, you define your for loop as such:

```
{ % for comment in content["comments"] % }
{ % endfor % }
```

But the problem is that you do not indicate this as a control structure, because you use `{ %`  and  `% }`, so Jinja does not know this is a control structure, or in your case, a for loop. If you fix your for loop declaration as shows:

```
{% for comment in content["comments"] %}
{% endfor %}
```

This code will work because you are now using the correct Jinja control structure syntax.

For more info, view the [Jinja documentation.](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#list-of-control-structures)